# What is wrong with this Palindrome function

Tags: java, recursion, palindrome

I wrote palindrome function in Java using Recursion but its printing the results incorrectly.

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String test) {
        if(test.length() == 1 || test.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Length is one");
            return true;

        } 

        if (test.charAt(0) == test.charAt(test.length() - 1)) {
            System.out.println("Length is one 111 a");
            isPalindrome(test.substring(1,test.length() -1)) ;      
        } 
        System.out.println("Length is one 111");
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        if(isPalindrome("rotor"))
            System.out.println(" Rotor is a palindrome");
        else
            System.out.println(" Rotor is not a palindrome");
        //System.out.println(isPalindrome("rotor"));
        //System.out.println(isPalindrome("motor"));
        //System.out.println(isPalindrome("a"));

    }
```

Output:

```
Length is one 111 a
Length is one 111 a
Length is one
Length is one 111
Length is one 111
 Rotor is not a palindrome
```

Comment: you forgot `return` inside `if`: `return isPalidrome(...)`.

Comment: Why did you use recursion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `return` statement inside the `if`. Without it, anything but a string of one or zero characters will ultimately return `false`:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String test) {
    if(test.length() <= 1) { // A more elegant check
        return true;
    } 

    if (test.charAt(0) == test.charAt(test.length() - 1)) {
        // "return" was missing here
        return isPalindrome(test.substring(1, test.length() -1)) ;      
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Also, your char comparison is case sensitive, which would still cause `Rotor` to fail.

Comment: @Zircon while OP's output is about `Rotor`, his `main` actually checks the string `rotor`. Although I agree, if we want to check for a "case insensitive palindrome", you should use `Character#equalsIgnoreCase` instead of a simple `==` for primitive `char`s. Or, alternatively lowercase (or uppercase) both characters.

Answer (score 1):

Your problems essentially stem from a poor solution technique. Recursion is a suboptimal way of solving this - think about all those stack frames that the JVM will have to create! If you are able to ditch the approach, and are willing to sacrifice performance for succinctness, then use

`return test.equalsNoCase(new StringBuilder(test).reverse().toString());`

which is obviously considerably easier to maintain (although this will create two extra objects *and* perform twice as many character comparisons as is strictly necessary). Use `equals` if you consider case as being important for palindromicity.

Answer (score 1):

You must add return here:

```
if (test.charAt(0) == test.charAt(test.length() - 1)) {
            System.out.println("Length is one 111 a");
            return isPalindrome(test.substring(1,test.length() -1)) ;
        }
        System.out.println("Length is one 111");
        return false;
```

If you don't do this, it will just continue to execute after you finish testing last call (in your case for string "t") and it will end with return false.